# ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command

Tags: python-3.x, module, jupyter

After I uninstalled all python and reinstalled it again jupyter notebook does not work. I have tried:

```
pip3 install jupyter notebook
pip3 install jupyter
pip3 install notebook
pip3 install jupyterlab
pip3 install ipython
```

and the pip3 install --user  and the pip and pip --user version of all above and still when i type

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

in my terminal i get the error

```
ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command
```

i am on mac if that has something to do with it.

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Installed anaconda and it is now magically fixed